# Let $F$ be a ﬁeld and $x, y\in F$. Prove:

Tags: proof-writing, axioms

Use field axioms to prove:

a) $(−1) · (−x) = x $

b) If $x · y = 0$ then $x = 0$ or $y = 0$

I don't understand how to approach these questions. Does the field include $1$ and $0$ as well?

Comment: Usually the field axioms state that $0$ denotes the additive identity and $1$ the multiplicative identity, and  that $0$ and $1$ are _distinct_ elements of the field. Thus, any field _does_ include $0$ and $1$ as well (at least according to the axioms that I know). What do _your_ field axioms say?

Comment: ) Closure. If x and y are in the field, then x+y and xy are in the field as well. 

2) Associativity. a(bc) = (ab)c, likewise for addition. 

3) Commutativity. ab = ba, likewise for addition. 

4) Distributivity. a(b+c) = ab + ac. (a+b)c = ac + bc. 

5) Identities. There must be elements, usually called 0 and 1, such that a+0 = a, and a*1 = a, for all a. 

6) Inverses. For every a, there must be elements b and c such that a+b = 0 and a*c = 1. In many nice fields, b is (-a) and c is (1/a).

Comment: Your Axiom 6) is troubling. If for **every** $a$, there exists an element $c$ such that $a*c = 1$, then $0$, the additive identity, also has a multiplicative inverse; that is, division by $0$ is defined since you give meaning to $c = 1/0$.

Answer (score 0):

For $a)$, we know that $(-x)+x=(-1)+1=0$, so

$(-1)(-x)=(-1)(-x)+(-x)+x=(-1+1)(-x)+x=0+x=x$

For $b)$ suppose that, for instance, $x \neq 0$. Since $F$ is a field, there exists $z \in F$ such that $z \cdot x= 1$. Hence: $x \cdot y=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $z (\cdot x \cdot y)=z \cdot 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $(z \cdot x) \cdot y=0$$\Rightarrow$ $y=0$

Answer (score 0):

a)
$$(1-1)\cdot(-x)=0$$
Add $x$ to both sides:
$$x+(1-1)\cdot(-x)=x$$
$x$ is the additive inverse of $(-x)$ so those two can cancel when added:
$$(-1)\cdot(-x)=x$$

b)
Suppose $x\cdot y=0$ and $x \neq 0$. Since this is a field, $x$ has an inverse.
$$x\cdot y=0$$
$$y=x^{-1}\cdot0$$
$$y=0$$
Hence if the product of two elements is $0$ and one of them is non-zero, then the other must be zero.

Comment: On the other hand, according to the OP's axioms (see his comment in response to my comment), there exists an element $z$ such that $0\cdot z = z\cdot 0 = 1$, and so $$(x\cdot y)\cdot z = 0\cdot z = 1$$ and since we began with the assumption that $x\cdot y = 0$, we are led to the result that $0 = 1$.

Comment: Doesn't this prove that $0$ cannot have a multiplicative inverse in any field unless it is the same as the additive inverse?